# C# Generated CSV changes the format of the data retrieved from a SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel

```
protected void ExportCSV(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DataTable ds = new DataTable();
ds.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[1] { new DataColumn("Name") });
foreach (GridViewRow roww in GridView1.Rows)

{
    if (roww.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkRow = (roww.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);

        if (chkRow.Checked)
        {
            string name = roww.Cells[1].Text;
            string DefaultConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DefaultConnection))

            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select AssignNumber, Stage.StageName,Stage.StationName,AspNetUsers.UserName,RecordedDateTime,StartTime,EndTime,Duration,PauseCount,PauseTotalTime,StageRecord.Count, StageRecord.Notes,Location,VarName,DropOut From TimingProfile Inner Join StudyRecord ON TimingProfile.TimingProfileID = StudyRecord.TimingProfileID Inner Join StageRecord ON StudyRecord.StudyRecordID = StageRecord.StudyRecordID Left Join Stage ON StageRecord.StageID = Stage.StageID Left Join VarAffect ON StageRecord.VarID = VarAffect.VarID Left Join MultiNameValue ON StudyRecord.StudyRecordID = MultiNameValue.StudyRecordID Left Join UserStage ON UserStage.StageID = Stage.StageID Left Join AspNetUsers ON UserStage.UserID = AspNetUsers.Id Where TimingProfile.Name = " + "'"+name+"'"))

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);

                            //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
                            string csv = string.Empty;

                            foreach (DataColumn column 
                            in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                                csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                            }

                            //Add new line.
                            csv += "\r\n";

                            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                                {
                                    //Add the Data rows.
                                    csv += row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                                }

                                //Add new line.
                                csv += "\r\n";
                            }
                            DateTime localdate = DateTime.Now;
                        //Download the CSV file.

                        Response.Clear();
                            Response.Buffer = true;
                            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MultiStation" + "" + name + " " + localdate + ".csv");

                        Response.Charset = "";
                            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                            Response.Output.Write(csv);

                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();

                    }
                }

            }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I used the query in SQL management studio the duration is shown as :00:32:39 but it appears in the generated CSV as 0.0226736111111111 instead. Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: Have you noticed that `0.0226736111111111*24*60` equals `32.65` (or `32:39`)?

Comment: yes, im quite sure its because the format was changed, from MM:SS:MS to the decimal value.

Comment: Can you do `TimeSpan.FromDays(0.0226736111111111).ToString()`? That gives me `"00:32:39"`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone needs to say it. This code shows loadsa enthusiasm and not much sophistication. You've mixed up UI (checkbox), business logic, data access, serialization and HTTP in **one method** ! And, predictably, there are problems. Your SQL is in string literals with concatenation, and hidden at the end is a glowing SQL injection vulnerability. Your serialization code, converting commas to semicolons, loses data and will produce invalid CSV (double quotes not doubled). Not using stringbuilder to construct the CSV will very likely cause performance issues. All these traps would be avoided by using libraries, Dapper or QueryFirst (disclaimer: which I wrote) for data access, servicestack for serialization.

Understanding how your data is stored, and how and when to format it, is really a core competence for a programmer. Often it's good to format at the last moment. If you were reusing sql requests, you might want to format in C#. Since this request is only used in this one place, you might want to format directly in the SQL. The downside is that the C# will not treat your duration as a duration. Try and use built-in date time formats before building your own.